# { } braces in model/views of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Been seeing some curly braces in a CodeIgniter model/views:

`mkdir("userdata/{$userID}/live/",0755,true);`

I know `$userID` is some type of variable which probably contains session user id of user. My question is how can set some values for me to use such `{ }`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`{$varname}` is an explicit way of specifying the border of the variable name

```
"$abcdefg"
```

in this case php will try to output the value of variable with name `abcdefg`

```
"{$a}bcdefg"
```

in this case it will output the value of the variable `a` and append it with string literal `bcdefg`.

So you can use **any** variable you have visible in current scope within curly braces

Comment: I want to note that curly braces are very common in my multi-language projects, it's pretty easy to translate them if you use them when retrieving object properties:
$lang = my_get_language();
$x = $this->my_model->GetRow(123)->row();
echo $this->{$lang."_title"};

if in your database structure you have 2 different fields like "en_title", "es_title", etc.

Comment: @Vlakarados: it is a great example of bad i18n implementation

Comment: Could you please state why is it bad?

Comment: @Vlakarados: because adding new language involves modifying of schema. Read about [Normal Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms)

Comment: Sorry if I sound offensive, but actually I'm just trying to figure it out. If I understand you say it's better to join a separate table with the language strings, and not putting them straight to the main table? But is it really necessary to do so in small projects, where I know there is little to no chance of adding new languages in the future? Also wouldn't it make the application work faster, because of less joining?

Comment: @Vlakarados: normalized schemes are easier to work with and are easier to maintain **and optimize**. You shouldn't optimize anything until you've found the part of the system that causes the bottleneck